# Vertical space between figures

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats

I really want to get rid of some of the whitespace between figures and subfigures, it is completley unecessary and sometimes causes a page of figures with a third landing on page two with text, while all could be on the same page, caption included if I could just remove some of the vertical whitespace...

```
\begin{figure}[H]


\centering
  \caption{Tidsutvikling bakgrunnstøy}
  \raisebox{-100}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{noise_f(t).png}}\\
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{noise_F(w).png}}\\
  \subfloat{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{noise_w(t).png}}
\end{figure}
```

I tried raisebox with minus value, pdflatex doesn't want, I have been googling for hours with no solution. How in gods name do I do this.

Edit: Answer to below question

```
\documentclass[norsk,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstrakt}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Innhold}
```

If I use `subfigure` the figures are so large that one of them gets cut off in the middle, if I use seperate `\begin{figure}` I will have the initial problem of too much white space. Two figures on a page then a third on page with text looks very bad.

Comment: Could you turn your snippet into a complete MWE including `documentclass` and the necessary packages?

Comment: `\raisebox` takes a dimension like `3pt` not  number like `-100` however you may just want `\vspace{-1cm}` or whatever rather than raising the box. If you are getting excessive space around the figures the most likely cause is that the png files themselves have white space in them. Finally figure[H] disables the float mechanism so its main function is to add vertical space to set of the figure, If you don't want the figure to float and don't want the space the figure environment is doing nothing. `capt-of` package will allow you to use captions without this.

Comment: It would also help if you provide a screen shot of the current (undesirable) output. Even though you may not have enough privileges, insert the image and remove the preceding `!`. Someone with edit privileges will re-embed the image in the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A reason for undesirable space often is caused by white space around the image. Putting the `\includegraphics` command inside an `\fbox` can reveal if this is the case, by showing the real bounding box:

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[<options>]{filename}}
```

When one discovers this to be the case, there are two strategies:

1. crop the graphics with some appropriate application, so that it has the correct bounding box;
2. crop the graphics within TeX by adding options such as `viewport` or `trim` (check the documentation of `graphicx`).

The second strategy requires usually a bit of trial and error.